# UML Use-case problem

Tags: uml, use-case

When drawing a UML usecase diagram ... activities which are processed by the system such as encryption comes as a 'usecase' ?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A use-case, as I understand it, involves some sort of an `Actor` (can be a user or another system) taking some sort of `Action` such as encrypting a message (via a GUI, or via an API call). However, if encryption is just a standard by-product of the users' actions and is really only dealt with within the system, then it would not be included in a usecase diagram.

Of course, your system could be composed of multiple independent libraries, one of which does encryption, and each library could have a set of use cases for their APIs, in which case that librarie's usecase diagram likely *would* include encryption as a usecase.

Comment: library use cases sound very ugly - they would probably often just map to all APIs...

Comment: @Gabriel - Hopefully, your use cases are rich enough and your library useful enough that multiple use cases map to the APIs, but yes, for a library, there is often a high corelation between use cases and what is available via the API. Use cases can also be used to show what a library is NOT supposed to be used for, which can also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I think use cases ought to be written from the point of view of the user, not the implementing system.  If the user wouldn't ask for encryption explicitly, I don't think it should appear as a separate use case.

Use cases ought to be concerned with "what" is implemented that's useful for the user, not the "how".

Comment: Exactly. Use cases are user-centric. But in the case of an API or a library, the user is another program. Depending on the scope or scale you are looking at, you can always find a User of some sort.